# Why some STL models turn to pure black in three.js scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8nws.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeJ8M.jpg)

I have some models(STL) turn to pure black while other models get color(from lights) correctly.

As you can see in Screenshot 1 and 2,the fighter got a nice color but the miku is totally black. It seems no light illuminates her or she behaves like being applied with black BasicMaterial.

The 2 models are applied with PhongMaterial. And I tried several combnations of lights with different position/type/parameter but it didn't work.

I'm sure about that the model of miku is normal. I just downloaded the fighter and miku from the same website,where they both displays with color. I also have some models which turn to pure black in my scene ,though they're normal STL model.

There must be some mistakes in my scene.

Here is my code:

```
    <script>
    var renderer;
    function initThree() {
        width = document.getElementById('canvas-frame').clientWidth;
        height = document.getElementById('canvas-frame').clientHeight;
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true
        });
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        document.getElementById('canvas-frame').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    }

    var camera;
    function initCamera() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 10000);
        camera.position.x = 50;
        camera.position.y = 0;
        camera.position.z = 0;
        camera.lookAt({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            z: 0
        });


    }


    var scene;
    function initScene() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();


    }


    //光源1
    var light;
    function initLight() {
        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xfefff7, 2.0, 0);
        light.position.set(0, 500, 0);
        scene.add(light);
    }
    //光源2
    var light2;
    function initLight2() {
        light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x414141, 1.0, 0);
        light2.position.set(0, -500, 0);
        scene.add(light2);
    }

    //此光源暂时无用
    var light3;
    function initLight3() {
        light3 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, .7, 0);
        light3.spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, .7, 0);
        light3.position.set(-700, 1000, 1000);
        light3.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(light3);
    }

    //此光源暂时无用
    var light4;
    function initLight4() {
        light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.7, 0);
        light4.position.set(3200, -3900, 3500);
        light4.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(light4);


    }

    //



    //创造木星
    var sphere;
    function initSphere() {
        var bitmap = new Image();
        bitmap.src = 'img/jupiter.jpg';
        var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(bitmap.src);
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map: texture
        });
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 64, 64);
        sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        sphere.position.set(0, 17, -120);
        scene.add(sphere);
    }

    //加载模型文件
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    function initLoad() {
        loader.addEventListener('load', function (event) {

            var geometryOfFiles = event.content;
            var materialOfFiles = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                wrapAround: true,
                wrapRGB: new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 1),
                color: 0xFFFFFF,
                specular: 0xFFFFFF,
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                shininess: 630,
                fog: false,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide

            });
            var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometryOfFiles, materialOfFiles);

            object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            object.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI / 111);
            object.scale.set(2, 2, 2);


            scene.add(object);


        });
        loader.load('miku.stl');
    }

    var loader1 = new THREE.STLLoader();
    function initLoad1() {
        loader1.addEventListener('load', function (event) {

            var geometryOfFiles = event.content;
            var materialOfFiles = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                wrapAround: true,
                wrapRGB: new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 1),
                color: 0xFFFFFF,
                specular: 0xFFFFFF,
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                shininess: 230,
                fog: false,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide

            });
            var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometryOfFiles, materialOfFiles);

            object.position.set(0, 20, 50);
            object.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI / 111);
            object.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);


            scene.add(object);


        });
        loader1.load('f35.stl');
    }


    var controls;
    function setControl() {
        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

        /*
         controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
         controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
         controls.panSpeed = 2;

         controls.noZoom = false;
         controls.noPan = false;

         controls.staticMoving = false;
         controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;*/
    }


    function animate() {
        controls.update();
        renderer.clear();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        sphere.position.x -= 0.1;
        sphere.rotation.y += -0.005;
    }

    function threeStart() {
        initThree();
        initCamera();
        initScene();
        initLight3();
        initLight4();
        initSphere();
        setControl();
        animate();
        initLoad();
        initLoad1();


    }



</script>
```

Comment: try adding THREE.AmbientLight , if the model changes color it probably has its normals calculated incorrectly or not at all...since you load both the same way it has to be a difference in the stl itself and i would check the normals first

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik   I added a AmbientLight, and the miku model changed color indeed. But if there are normals misktakes in miku , why I can view it normally on the website Thingiverse.com where I downloaded it ? Actually some models with normals mistakes still can be loaded in three.js normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seeing that adding an AmbientLight helped it will probably be normals calculated incorrectly or missing altogether check them here

```
geometry.faces[0].normal;
```

and to calculate the correct values call

```
geometry.computeFaceNormals()
```

To answer your question about how thingiverse shows them correct: after looking at their code I noticed they dont actually use those STL files they provide, but have a JSON file to load from (using THREE.JSONLoader)

these files have normals correct(they might have done some precalculations on files uploaded by users) but you would have to check the STL yourself

the miku JSON file can be found at http://thingiverse-production-new.s3.amazonaws.com/threejs_json/51/67/c8/34/6d/293cd764miku.js

Comment: Great analysis , thank you!  I never thought Thingiverse provides different models for displaying(repaired) and downloading(origin)......

Answer (score 2):

don't know if `computeFaceNormals()` is outdated, but in my case i had to do:

```js
const caseGeometry = useLoader(STLLoader, CaseObject)
caseGeometry.computeVertexNormals()
```

works like a charm, though